# How to open sessions in Spyder 3?

Tags: session, spyder

It seems that Spyder 3 does no longer make use of sessions (i.e. list of opened files). Now I have several Spyder 2 sessions which I can no longer open with Spyder 3.

Is there an alternative to looking inside the session `.tar` file and opening the files manually one by one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder developer here*) Sessions were merged with Projects in Spyder 3. Since sessions are not used anymore, we removed all code related to them in this new version.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: What does "merged" mean exactly? In Spyder 3 is there a way to save the list of opened files (not descendants of same directory) and later restore them?

Comment: It means that a project has the ability to save the list of open files in the Editor, even if they don't belong to the main directory defined for the project.